# Open File using Notepad and Copy data to Excel in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have a csv file that is pipe delimited. I want to know if there is any way in c# so that it will open the file in notepad, then copy the data to excel. I want this specific step to be performed, not just a simple copy and paste.

The issue is that the file is getting corrupted if I open it directly through excel.

Hence, opening it first using notepad, copying it to a new excel file and then doing the remaining operations in excel. This gives correct output, unlike opening the file via Excel.

Can someone please let me know if this can be achieved in c#?

Comment: You mean you want to import a `|` delimited csv file to excel? Or that you're not sure of the character encoding of the original csv file? Including/attaching it might help discover the actual issue. Otherwise, you can simply open and save with new encoding.

Comment: In short, yes you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read a whole file as a `System.Text.StringBuilder` and replace `|` with `,`. Now try to open the file with Excel, it will open without any issue.

Sample Code

```
System.Text.StringBuilder str= File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\test.csv");
```